Checking a PR's commits are all descendants of destination branch
In our team we have a requirement for our PRs: they need to be rebased before being merged, in order to achieve a "semi-linear history". I'm looking for an automated way to evaluate this requirement (we know how to run a script as part of GitHub's checks, but I need help with the git commands that make the evaluation itself). For now we only need to determine if a rebase is necessary.
Our goal for a PR is this: destination branch is at commit D, PR branch is at commit P.
a-b-c-D
       \
        m-n-o-P

So that when the PRs are merged history looks like this
a-b-c-D---------q-----T-----W
       \       / \   / \   /
        m-n-o-P   r-s   u-v

We can block PRs that branch out from commits that are older than D (for example a, b or c), both with GitHub's settings (require branch to be up-to-date, and using git merge-base --is-ancestor), but there are some scenarios that are not being prevented.
For example this is something we can detect: PR branched out from commit C, which is an ancestor of D where the destination branch is currently. In this case we'd want the branch to be rebased on top of D.
a-b-C-D
     \
      m-n-o-P

What I'm struggling is to detect when there are merges involved. As in this example: destination branch 'main' is in commit X, PR branch pr_branch is in commit J (in this case main can be fast-forwarded to J, but there are some commits d, f that are not part of that path X->z->g->J)
    (main is here)
         |
a--b--c--X--z
       \     \
        d--f--g--J
                 ^
            (pr_branch is here)

In this case neither git merge-base --is-ancestor nor github flag this. The merge base detected would be X (by running git merge-base main pr_branch).
What I want to check for and I can't articulate with git commands is:
The PR is valid if:

pr_branch is fast-forward'able from main
all commits in the range main..pr_branch are descendants of main (in the last example, d and f don't meet this rule)
merge-commits are only acceptable if they are descendants of the destination branch (i.e. part of the PR branch) AND all the parents of the merges are the destination branch or descendants of it.

In general merges are not the problem, but commits that are not reachable by fast-forwarding from destination branch.
In this example we can check for 1, but I don't know how to test for #2.
Running git rev-list main..pr_branch gives me a list of commits: J, g, f, d, Z.
The commits d and f are what should make the PR fail the check, since those are not descendant of main (currently at X). I could run git merge-base --is-ancestor for each of the commits I got with rev-list, but I wonder if there is a better or more correct way to do this? Maybe a git command that already exists instead of having to write a script? Can rev-list be used to use set operations like union or intersection (similar to in a Venn diagram) ?
I checked some other questions like git merge: enforce both linear history AND merge commits, but the script offered there doesn't seem to detect this case.
The feature in GitHub that we tried but didn't catch this case is
Keeping your pull request in sync with the base branch

Would it be possible for your team to require fast forward merges instead of merge commits? This would prevent a feature branch from being merged multiple times into main

Feature branches get deleted once the PR is merged. And also we like the merge commits since those delimit where a PR 'starts' and 'ends'.

I'm looking at the last git graph (the unwanted one) and the only way that can arise is if someone forgot to rebase before merging. If they rebased, then X would be the new merge-base.
Also, to have commit J present means that the feature branch wasn't deleted/was resurrected after it was merged, which inherently makes things messy. I'm interested by this problem, but I think git merge --ff-only might help the "check if PR can be fast forwarded" part

Do a rebase. If it has no effect it can be merged. Do a merge. As a sanity check make sure that the first parent of the merge is the commit you rebased on.

The question is Git-specific. Consider changing tag rebase to git-rebase.

@NFeruch-FreePalestine The reasons for how we got into this messy situation are not very important. Yes a developer made some mistakes, what we want to do is catch those mistakes before we merge the PR, so that more junior devs can catch their own mistakes right as they create/modify the PR, without needing the code reviewer to manually check the branchs are ok. The feature branch wasn't resurected, the dev just made some mistakes while rebasing/pulling I guess, and pushed the result w/o checking.

@Guildenstern good catch, ty. I've changed the tag

Check that there is no merge commits between main and pr_branch:
# the following list should be empty:
git log --merges main..pr_branch

# for example:
merges=$(git log --oneline --merges main..pr_branch)
if [[ -n $merges ]]; then
    echo "There should be no merge commits in your branch:"
    echo "$merges"
    exit 1
fi

So your complete check could be: check that target branch is an ancestor of the PR's head, and that there are no merge commits "in between"

Exactly. It shouldn’t be more complicated than the existing checks plus this. But it’s early in the morning for me.

That seems that it will prevent a feature branch that contain merge-commits, even if all the commits (including the merges) are descendants of the target branch.

@frozenkoi: if some commits are descendants of main, they will not appear in main..[anything else]. The definition of the main.. part is "only commits that are not reachable from main"  (equivalent to ^main, documented in git help gitrevisions )

nit:  (but I guess it's a soap box of mine).  Error messages belong on stderr: echo "There should be no ..." >&2.  Or if [[ -n "$merges" ]] ...; fi >&2

@LeGEC I think there's some confusion here about "descendants" (aka children). main..feat excludes the parents of main, not the children. git rev-list main..feat would list the commits in between. In the example of the question, if we do git rev-list c..J we would get commits x, z, d, f, g and J

in that case: the OP's requirement was precisely to have no merge commits on feature branches
